# Roslyn - Type of TypedConstant.Value for a typeof expression

Tags: c#, roslyn, typeof, roslyn-code-analysis

If I have some source code with a `typeof` expression, eg, in an attribute, what should I cast the `TypedConstant`'s `Value` property to? I can't find this information documented anywhere.

For example, I have the following source code:

```
class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
    public FooAttribute(Type type) {}
}

[Foo(typeof(int))]
class Bar {}
```

and I want to look at `Foo`'s argument in my analyser:

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
class MyAnalyser : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterCompilationAction(LookAtFooArg);
    }

    private void LookAtFooArg(CompilationAnalysisContext context)
    {
        TypedConstant argumentTypedConstant = context.Compilation
            .GetTypeByMetadataName("Bar")
            .GetAttributes()
            .Single()
            .ConstructorArguments
            .Single();
        // Value here is typed as an object. What should I cast it to?
        var typeOfExpressionValue = argumentTypedConstant.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll be an `INamedTypeSymbol`. I learned this using good ole-fashioned guesswork.

```
var typeOfExpressionValue = (INamedTypeSymbol)argumentTypedConstant.Value;
```

Comment: The best way to investigate this kind of question is using Roslyn's Syntax Visualizer in VS.  You can right-click a node and click Get Constant Value.

Comment: Looking at the [reference source](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/TypedConstant.cs,97), it might also be a `ImmutableArray<TypedConstant>` or even [something else](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/TypedConstant.cs,110) so you may need to be careful.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, it's typed as an `object` so it could be anything. If I'd written `[Foo(3)]` the argument's `Value` would be an `int`. In this instance I happen to know that `Foo`'s constructor only takes a `Type`, so it can only be called with a `typeof` expression, so (I _think_) `Value` will definitely be an `ITypeSymbol`.

Comment: @SLaks Cool, I didn't know Syntax Visualiser existed. Thanks!

Comment: Although, "View Constant Value" doesn't seem to work for `typeof` expressions. Seems like a bug.